# A Question about Theorem 1.5 of I.Rivin "Large Galois groups with applications to Zariski density"

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand Theorem 1.5 of I. Rivin's paper [*Large Galois groups with applications to Zarsiki density*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3009).

Its says:

"If $G$ is $Sn(n,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\Gamma < G$ is such that it contains
one element $γ_1$ with Galois group of characteristic polynomial equal to $S_n$ and another
element $γ_2$ such that $γ_2$ is of infinite order and does not commute with $γ_1$, then $\Gamma$ is
Zariski-dense in G. If $G$ is $Sp(n,\mathbb Z)$, and $\Gamma < G$ contains elements $γ_1, γ_2$ as above, then either $\Gamma$ is Zariski-dense in $G$ or the Zariski closure of $\Gamma$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) is the product of n copies
of $Sl(2,\mathbb C)$."

Rivin says that it follows immediately from Theorem 9.10 of Prasad's and Rapinchuk's paper ["Generic elements in Zariski-dense subgroups and isospectral locally symmetric spaces"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.1217), but I do not understand why.

The case $G=Sl(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is clear. For the case $G=Sp(n,\mathbb{Z})$: If it is true that the closure of $\Gamma$ is a subgroup generated by a maximal torus $T$ and the corresponding one-parameter unipotent subgroups $U_a$ for $a\in \Phi(G,T)$ positive roots, as it is said in the paper of Prasad and Rapinchuk. Why should such a subgroup look like $n$-copies of $Sl(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Thank you for your answers!